# How to get axios.post to update my API with Click button ? (Help)

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, post

**My GET & POST Axios code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import Card from "../../molecules/Card";
import Button from "../../atoms/Button";
import Axios from "axios";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Fetch
    // fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    //   .then(res => res.json())
    //   .then(json => setUsers(json.data));

    //Axios
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3004/users").then((res) => setUsers(res.data));
  }, [users]);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const data = {
      email: "angelin.veronica@mail.com",
      first_name: "Angelin",
      last_name: "Veronica",
      avatar: "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg",
    };
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3004/users", data);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}> Home Screen </Text>

      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <Button label="Update" onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
        {users.map((item) => (
          <Card
            key={item.id}
            fullName={`${item.first_name} ${item.last_name}`}
            // name={item.name}
            // username={item.username}
            email={item.email}
            imageUrl={item.avatar}
            // address={`${item.address.street}, ${item.address.suite}, ${item.address.city}, ${item.address.zipcode}`}
            // phone={item.phone}
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

my API=
[
{
"id": 7,
"email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
"first_name": "Michael",
"last_name": "Lawson",
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
},
{
"id": 8,
"email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
"first_name": "Lindsay",
"last_name": "Ferguson",
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"
},
{
"id": 9,
"email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in",
"first_name": "Tobias",
"last_name": "Funke",
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg"
},
{
"id": 10,
"email": "byron.fields@reqres.in",
"first_name": "Byron",
"last_name": "Fields",
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg"
},
{
"id": 11,
"email": "george.edwards@reqres.in",
"first_name": "George",
"last_name": "Edwards",
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg"
},
{
"id": 12,
"email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in",
"first_name": "Rachel",
"last_name": "Howell",
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg"
},
{
"id": 13,
"email": "maestro.pythagoras@gmail.com",
"first_name": "Maestro",
"last_name": "Pythagoras",
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg"
}
]

- HELP: I can access the API and retrieve data from my local API, but when made the button, I don't know where the error is, because when I did an update on the button, my API was not updated at all, can someone help me in solving this problem, Thank you in advance.

Comment: you mean it's not at all calling `handleSubmit` on click of update button?

Comment: Yes sir, at const handleSubmit I just add manual data for update on my API, but I confused why didn't work.

Comment: check the `Button` component do you have `onSubmit` in that? it might be `onClick`